# Struct returning function in C++ class before struct definition

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, struct

I have a tree-structure class named `SuperTree` in my C++ program and I want it to have an instance method that returns a `struct` or `pair` which one of the attributes is a pointer to a `SuperTree` object.

The `insert` function in my `SuperTree` class should return a `Res` struct, which contains a reference to another `SuperTree` object and a boolean value. However, if I try to compile the code, I get the following error message:

`supertree.cpp:24: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Res’ with no type`

I also can't define the `Res` struct before my `SuperTree` class because it'd would not compile either. Maybe it's some case for C++ generic types or something (which I don't know how to use yet).

So this was my attempt:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

class AVL {
public:
    int key;
    int bf;
    AVL* leftChild;
    AVL* rightChild;

    AVL()
    {
    }

    ~AVL() {};

    AVL rotateLeft();
    AVL rotateRight();

    Res* insert(int value);

    int remove();
    int size();
};

// typedef pair<AVL, bool> result;

typedef struct result {
  struct AVL *avl;
  bool changed;
} Res;
```

Notice that the `pair` definition is commented out, but I you guys can answer for them too I'd be glad!

So that's it, how can I have both the `SuperTree` class and `Res` struct and a `Res` pointer returning function in my `SuperTree` class?

Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case when two classes or structs must reference each other, you need to add a forward declaration for one or the other, like this:

```
struct Res; // No typedef is necessary in C++
class AVL {
    ...
    Res* insert(int value);
};
struct Res {
    AVL *avl;
    bool changed;
};
```

Note that `pair<AVL*,bool>` would work as well instead of `Res`, letting you skip the forward declaration:

```
class AVL {
    ...
    std::pair<AVL*,bool> insert(int value);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Because neither class needs to know another's size at the time of definition, you can use **forward declarations**.

1. You can declare `AVL` first:

   ```
   class AVL;  // forward declaration

   typedef struct result {
     // Type size information not necessary at declaration time
     // for pointer and reference members,
     // so a forward declaration is enough at this point.
     struct AVL *avl;
     bool changed;
   } Res;

   class AVL {
   public:
   ...
       Res* insert(int value);
   };
   ```
2. Or declare `Res` first:

   ```
   struct Res;  // forward declaration

   class AVL {
   public:
   ...
       // Type size information is not necessary for return values
       // at function declaration time, so a forward declaration
       // is enough at this point.
       // Note: you can even return by value here.
       Res* insert(int value);
   };

   struct Res {
     struct AVL *avl;
     bool changed;
   };
   ```

Note that you don't have to typedef a struct in C++ like in C, because you can use type name without "struct" keyword, so `struct Res {...}` and `typedef struct result {...} Res` should be the same, except you can't forward-declare the latter.